# V8 engine: why object spread at the start of new object create new hidden classes only after ninth element? Otherwise if spread at the end - its ok

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, v8, spread

I just read about hidden classes and inline caching. I found interesting performance thing, that break my mind.

So, we have the following code:

```
const n = 100000;
const array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  array.push({ a: '2', b: '3', c: '4', d: '5' });
}

const date1 = Date.now();
const array1 = array.map(i => ({ someNewField1: 'test1', someNewField2: 'test2', ...i }))
console.log('first map: ', Date.now() - date1);

const date2 = Date.now();
const array2 = array.map(i => ({ ...i, someNewField: 'test1', someNewField2: 'test2', }))
console.log('second map:', Date.now() - date2);
```

if you run this on your computer you will see that the first map loop ran 5 times faster than the second.

I ran this snippet in the chrome console and got memory snapshot. As i could see, in first case i got new array(array1), where all objects have same hidden class (map). So this array.map loop ran fast. But in the second case, i got new array(array2) where only 9 first elements have the same Hidden Class which has back pointers to Hidden Class from origin array(array) elements. But other elements in the second array(array2) have unique Hidden Classes, which have no any back pointers. Also i noticed that access to object fields from array2 is slow.

So i think, that after first 9 elements V8 engine started to create slow-properties objects, but why?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a case where several optimizations are interfering with one another in a way that makes the end result less optimized than it should be. Reported at [crbug.com/v8/13303](https://crbug.com/v8/13303).

**2023 Update**: This issue is [fixed](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/99177d1c592d9501f6339fd0e6ee09a9fdad6b04) in Chrome 117.

Answer (score 1):

TurboFan (the V8 optimizing compiler) performs several **speculative optimizations** of the bytecode generated by Ignition (the V8 interpreter).

These optimizations are based on several assumptions that TurboFan makes about your code. If these assumptions do not hold at runtime, V8 has to perform some **de-optimizations** and go back to the original, less-performant bytecode generated by Ignition.

You might try using this tool to check if any de-optimization occurs: https://github.com/andrewiggins/v8-deopt-viewer

Comment: "*If these assumptions do not hold at runtime*" sounds like the assumptions were made at compile time. But rather, they are inferred from profiling the code until the optimising compiler kicks in. The assumptions already *did* hold at runtime for all the past encountered values, the speculation is that the values won't change in the future.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't express myself correctly.

Comment: Turbofan is not involved here (at least not in the root cause; of course if you run anything long enough then Turbofan will kick in).